# Bootstrap Enable/Disable Chosen Select Dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

Does anyone know how I can dynamically enable/disable a Bootstrap Chosen select box?
I created a JSFiddle with two select boxes.
The first is just to toggle the enable/disable of the chosen select.

```
$(document).on('change','#option', function(){
   // not sure what to do here
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yakitori/H38fU/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your jQUery to the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change','#option',function(){
        if($(this).val() == 1){
            // enable select box
            $("#chzn-select").attr('disabled', false).trigger("liszt:updated");
        }else{
            // disable select box
            $("#chzn-select").attr('disabled', true).trigger("liszt:updated");
        }
        $("#option").trigger("chzn:updated");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');  after execution of your codes ... :)